# List View Adapter with url image

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Hello I have one List view example with image in drawable folder...but i need get image Foto from url 
how to change drawable to string url to work fine.

i'm newbie in android,sorry.

```
public class list_view_comments {

    protected Drawable foto;
    protected String nombre;
    protected String cargo;
    protected long id;

    public list_view_comments(Drawable foto, String nombre, String cargo) {
        super();
        this.foto = foto;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public list_view_comments(Drawable foto, String nombre, String cargo, long id) {
        super();
        this.foto = foto;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cargo = cargo;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Drawable getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(Drawable foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand your question.

Comment: this code is my adapter

Comment: and i have my aray    ListView lista =(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_list_views);
        ArrayList<list_view_comments> arraydir = new ArrayList<list_view_comments>();
        list_view_comments list_view_comments;

Comment: list_view_comments = new list_view_comments(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher), "Arianna Huffington", "Presidenta");
        arraydir.add(list_view_comments);                               list_view_adapter adapter = new list_view_adapter(getActivity(), arraydir);                                                          lista.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: i don't see any adapter here. are you using this class in an adapter? if so, how?

Comment: you'll need to modify your adapter to accept a url instead of a drawable (you'll need a custom adapter if you don't already have one.). I recommend you take a look at the Picasso library for loading the url into the imageview

Comment: public class list_view_comments{} is my adapter only example create i send drawable android image bue i need send array from json url image in my adapter how to change drawable to string url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using a Library Aquery for this answer solved 
https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Answer (score 0):

Drawables dont have URIs. however u can parse them and this is how u do it:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/image_name");
```

Comment: that is **quite** different.

Answer (score 0):

Directly specifying web url on android view is not possible.
You have to download the image from url, store it in some location and then use it in the Imageview

```
File image = new  File(storedPath);

if(image.exists()){
  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());
  ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_xyz);
  myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

downloading should be done asynchronously when using listview for list view scroll to be smooth. Final output you need to target is like, user keep scrolling the list, images slowly appear as and when downloading is completed. Lot of other optimization technics guide-lined by android should be used to get the best performance(convertViews, viewHolder etc)

Comment: i need get a image from url.. but dont save image in android proyect

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = .. ;//get the download image to ByteArrayOutputStream
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length); // decode from memory directly